How can I implement a Django queryset into an HTML datalist
I am creating my own ERP system and I have it completely operational. I have a problem in which the user cannot seem to find articles which they want to add to the order. So I was looking at trying to do this 100% HTML.
My idea is the following:
In forms.py I have defined my article queryset like this:
self.fields['article'].queryset = Article.objects.filter(deleted=False)

Then I have my widgets like this :
'article' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'input', 'list':articles})

The articles list is :
<!-- Datalists -->
<datalist id="articles">
  {% for article in articles %}
    <option value='{{article.id}}'>[{{article.articlenumber}}] {{article.name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</datalist>

Then in the form the articleid is sent as article. So I pick that up and in my views then:
article = request.POST.get('article')
article = Article.objects.get(id=article)


While making this question, I solved my own problems.
So what you need to do in your forms.py is :
class Meta:
    ## Your own models and include/excludes here ##
    widgets = {
    'article' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'input', 'list':'articles', 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
    }#Autocomplete off just to only show real articles when clicking in the input

In your template.html file you add this to create a datalist which was defined in forms.py.
I added this to the top op the file, the id value of the datalist has to be exactly the same as the list attribute on the widget in your forms.py:
  <datalist id="articles">
  {% for article in articles %}
    <option value='{{article.id}}'>[{{article.articlenumber}}] {{article.name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</datalist>

Then in your views.py you add :
articles = Article.objects.filter(deleted=False)
#form.is_valid() starts here:
article = request.POST.get('article')
article = Article.objects.get(id=article)
neworderline = neworderlineform.save(commit=False)
neworderline.article = article
## all other stuff you want to do
neworderlineform.save()

Don't forget to add articles to your context, so your template can get that data.
If there is anything unclear let me know!
